# Mysql type hidden type casting

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to improve an old system (written ages ago) where every mysql queries are glued from string. So example of that query looks like

```
"SELECT * FROM User WHERE id > '3'"
```

Id column is of course bigint and PK.

What does mysql do with '3' in query where id should be a int value? I assume it is treated as a string (due to '') so this value is casted into int during analyze/optimize process by mysql. Am I right?

//UPDATE
I probably asked wrong way. There are two way to handle it.

1. (Fast) Mysql automatically detects that id should be int and rewrite/cast a query to

   ```
    SELECT * FROM User WHERE id > 3
   ```

   before send it to DB engine
2. (Unbelievable) Mysql does

   ```
   SELECT * FROM
   ```

   then in loop apply condition  WHERE id > '3' and cast it for EVERY row

I just want to be sure that second option is impossible.

Comment: In that case, the string ('3') is automatically casted into int (or bigint in your case, probably) indeed, as far as I know.

Comment: This question can be solved in approx 2.4 seconds if you just try it yourself and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL will always cast the string to a number for comparing, which in this case this is the right thing to do (it will use the index on the column to find the values).
If your column is a string and you compare it to an integer constant MySQL will cast the column to an integer and not use the index.

Comment: will Mysql cast it once or for every row in my case?

Comment: It should cast it only once, but i don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL will automatically cast it into the correct column type. If it cannot for some reason, it will throw an error.

Make sure to use prepared statements with PDO or MySQLi in any case where the parameter may come from an unsafe source (the user, an external API).

Comment: @mrok: My answer has not changed. MySQL will cast the correct type in the query.

Comment: yes of course, but how many cast operation mysql does - one or as many as rows exist in the table?

Comment: @mrok: One for each parameter you put in the query. In which case, one.